# I don't know how to word this better

Tags: grammaticality

"To hear opinion beyond from my friends and family."

Is there a better way to word this ?

All I can think of is "To hear opinion other than my friends and family."
But I want to sound little more serious, rather than casual.

English isn't my first language. I would like to hear some feedback from others.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better phrasing may be:

"To hear opinions other than those of my friends and family."

I might mention that this phrase is not a sentence by itself.  You may be focusing on only a portion of a full sentence to pose your question, but something must come either before or after this fragment:

"One reason why I want to attend college in the United States is to hear opinions other than those of my friends and family."  OR

"To hear opinions other than those of my friends and family, I use the Internet to stream news from radio and television programs and to read newspapers online."

Personally, I would not favor "...to hear opinions beyond those of my friends and family" because a reader could possibly conclude that "beyond" may connote that these other opinions are more extreme that those of your friends and family.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I only typed a portion of the sentence I was struggling with. Perhaps, I should type the full sentence next time.

Comment: Good idea, I think that would result in more helpful responses.   Best of luck!